# Alternative to Apache’s .htaccess file for IIS?

Tags: iis, .htaccess, server-migration

I'm moving a WordPress blog from Apache to IIS. It's just for a couple weeks until I get it changed out. But all I can get to is the homepage. Everything else throws errors.

I think my problem is in the .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
#END WordPress
```

Is there something equivalent to this for IIS?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using IIS or Apache on Windows?

Comment: additionally, what kind of error does it throw ?

Comment: Using IIS. The error: If I click on a link that has a subdirectory, like mysite.com/news, I get a 404 error. 

If I add /index.php in the address bar, I get no input file specified.

Answer (score 10):

I think you would find the answer here - [How To Set Pretty Permalinks in Wordpress Runs On IIS 7](http://web.archive.org/web/20120626010209/http://www.geekblogger.org/2010/03/how-to-set-pretty-permalinks-in.html) I guess you need to put one web.config file in the root folder like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <remove value="index.php" />
    <add value="index.php" />
  </files>
 </defaultDocument>
<rewrite>
 <rules>
     <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url=".*" />
         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
     </rule>
 </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

> "Pretty" permalinks usually require
>   mod_rewrite, and IIS (common on
>   Windows servers) does not support
>   mod_rewrite.

Check Wordpress Codex, specifically [Permalinks Without Mod Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite) section since it has information about permalinks in your environment (some information below, check the link for full information since it's the official documentation):

> If you are using IIS 7 and have admin
>   rights on your server, you can use
>   Microsoft's URL Rewrite Module
>   instead. Though not completely
>   compatible with mod_rewrite, it does
>   support WordPress's pretty permalinks.
>   Once installed, open the web.config
>   file in the WordPress folder and add
>   the following rule to the
>   system.webServer element.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

> "Pretty" permalinks usually require
>   mod_rewrite, and IIS (common on
>   Windows servers) does not support
>   mod_rewrite.

whether you are using IIS6 or 7, you can also use a rewriting engine on IIS - many of them support mod_rewrite syntax.
[IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com) is a good one, works with both IIS6 and 7. (Vista, WS2003, 2008).

Answer (score 0):

Wound up doing a new install of WordPress then selectively importing the tables.

The problem was the permalinks of course. But I found the easiest way to fix it was to use the same structure permalinks the old site did (luckily it hasn't been deleted yet so I could find it in the admin) and then importing everything except the user tables.

If you import the user tables, you lose the admin login from the new setup.